# Bookmarklet That Changes the Background to Your URL

Tags: javascript, bookmarklet

I have been trying to make a bookmarklet that changes the background to the URL you provide the the a prompt.

```js
javascript:var newImage = prompt("URL Image", "url('https://i.ytimg.com/vi/Lr5E2KBfEGE/maxresdefault.jpg')");var wae=document.body;wae.style.backgroundImage=newImage,wae.style.backgroundRepeat="no-repeat",wae.style.backgroundAttachment="fixed";void 0;
```

So far I have been successful, but the prompt will always have "url('https://i.ytimg.com/vi/Lr5E2KBfEGE/maxresdefault.jpg')"
Is it possible to make it so all you have to enter in the prompt is just the URL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply don't pass the second parameter in the `prompt` field, and append the return of the prompt to the backgroundImage.

```js
var newImage = prompt("URL Image");
var wae = document.body;
wae.style.backgroundImage = "url(" + newImage + ")", wae.style.backgroundRepeat = "no-repeat", wae.style.backgroundAttachment = "fixed";
void 0;
```

Answer (score 2):

Also you could try this:

```
var newImage = prompt("URL Image", 
"https://i.ytimg.com/vi/Lr5E2KBfEGE/maxresdefault.jpg")
newImage = 'url('+newImage+') no-repeat'
$('body').css({'background':newImage})
```